# Prove an identity of integral equations

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

I tried to prove this:
[equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQvLG.png)

And I came to:
[u=1-x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4E6r.png)

But now if I replace u by x-1, I get the same equation that needed to be proven.
So I do not know actually what to do...
Could someone help me?

Comment: It looks like you are done.  Why do you say your conclusion is the same as where you started?  You started with an integration variable raised to the power $n$, now it is raised to the power $m$, which is exactly what you wanted to prove. You can call the integration variable anything you like, $x, u, w, z$, whatever.  $\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_a^b f(z)dz$.

Comment: Don't let the name of the variable trip you up. You have already proved the result you are seeking and just because you called it $u$ instead of $x$ doesn't make it a different polynomial.

Comment: Thank you! But u=1-x so x is not equal to u? How can I prove that it is?

Comment: In other words:  "Thank you, but, let me ignore everything you just said"?

Comment: @Michael No, because I think in the way that x=1-u so x is not equal to u?

Comment: Do you disagree that for general functions $f$ we have $\int_a^b f(t)dt = \int_a^b f(w)dw$ ?

Comment: No, not if t=w. But in this case let's say x=1 then u=0 so x is not equal to u?

Comment: You seem to be putting an extra condition "if $t=w$" on my equation $\int_a^b f(t)dt = \int_a^b f(w)dw$.  Are you suggesting there may be a situation where the equation is not true, such as when your extra condition is somehow not satisfied?  Can you give an example where it is not true?

Comment: Please explain me why you can say that x=u even though you just said that u=1-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx$$

is the area under the curve of $f(x)$ as $x$ goes from $a$ to $b$.

The integral

$$\int_a^b f(u) du$$

is the area under the curve of $f(u)$ as $u$ goes from $a$ to $b$.

These are the same area: $x$ and $u$ are called dummy variables because it doesn't matter which letter you use, the area is the same, because you're adding up the same values of the same function in your Riemann sum. In a similar way,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k,$$

because again, $n$ and $k$ are simply dummy variables. One last example to make this notion clear: if you add up

$$\sum_{n=1}^3 n \qquad \textrm{or} \qquad \sum_{k=1}^3 k$$

you will get

$$1+2+3=6$$

from both sums. The takeaway: It does not matter what the dummy variable is called. It is irrelevant whether we already used a letter for a previous substitution.

Answer (score 2):

You are done with the problem and you do not have to do anything else.

Note that x or u are dummy variables and you may 
 simply change u to x as your last step.

Comment: Thank you! But u=1-x so x is not equal to u? How can I prove that it is?

Comment: Please pay attention to the comments made by Michael.

Comment: Let's say x=1 then u=0 so x is not equal to u?

Comment: Note that you get the same ansewer for $\int _0^1 x^2 dx $ and $\int _0^1 t^2 dt $ so changing x to t does not change the answer.

Comment: Yes but you didn't define that t=1-x

Comment: You do not have to change u to 1-x in your last step. Just change u to x and your are done.

Comment: But I can not do that if I can't understand why?

Comment: So $u=1-x$ but you forgot that you did an integral transform. That is a non-trivial process and you used the properties of integrals to make that change. You can't just do it without the integral sign helping you through the substitution method. That's why the name of the variable is immaterial here.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thank you, but can you clarify "the properties of integrals" that allow me to say x=u?

Comment: @Grocerystore so the substitution method is essentially the inverse of the chain rule for derivatives. You're using function composition through substitutions to change the integral so that it has a different form and we can do that because of the fundamental theorem of calculus. You can add an extra layer, say substitute $x=t$ then $t=u$ and $u=1-x$ if you want the final result to have the name $x$ but you didn't add anything by using $t$ to change the names of the variables around.

Comment: Thank you, but you can't say that x=t and t=u if 1-x=u because x=1-u so x=1-t so x is not equal to t...